# Android two ListView - two OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview

I have two ListView side by side in my activity and i want to only make it possible to select one item in one list at a time.

But right now if i select one item then one in the other list, the selections in both list are cleared, which is strange because when i check which listeners is called using logs everything seems to be working the way it should.

Also if i keep selecting different items at some point they start working like there was nothing in the listener because no list is cleared and i can select one item in each list. But i want to only be able to select one at a time so that's why i tried to reset the selection of the other ListView when you select an item in one of the two.

This code is at the end of the method where i initialize the ListViews.

selectedT1 and selectedT2 are initialized at -1

```
team1ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterV, View v, int position, long id) {
            selectedPlayer = (String) adapterV.getItemAtPosition(position);
            selectedT1 = position;
            if(selectedT2 > -1){
                team2ListView.clearChoices();
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                selectedT2 = -1;
            }
        }
    });
team2ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterV, View v, int position, long id) {
            selectedPlayer = (String) adapterV.getItemAtPosition(position);
            selectedT2 = position;
            if(selectedT1 > -1){
                team1ListView.clearChoices();
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                selectedT1 = -1;
            }
        }
    });
```

The xml of my listviews if it can help, they both are single choice and i have a button under them to validate the choice made but for that i need to be able to only select one of the items and not one in each list.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:id="@+id/team1ListView"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:listSelector="#666666"/>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:id="@+id/team2ListView"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:listSelector="#666666"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: what does method 'clearChoices()' ?

Comment: can you show how do you populate the data in the lists? adapters?

Comment: adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, playersT1Names);
        team1ListView.setAdapter(adapter1);